# trouble getting attributes from XML elements using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I am parsing out attributes and values from some XML returned from a third party API and I am getting inconsistent results. The XML looks like this:

```
<propertyMetrics month="12" year="2013" propertyId="3923837">
  <metric name="siteTotal" uom="kBtu" dataType="numeric">
    <value>409249.0</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="waterUseTotal" uom="kgal" dataType="numeric">
    <value>2434.2</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="totalGHGEmissions" uom="MtCO2e" dataType="numeric">
    <value>28.5</value>
  </metric>
  <metric name="greenPowerOnSite" dataType="numeric">
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
  </metric>
</propertyMetrics>
```

I use the following code in LINQPad to query the XML:

```
var propMetrics = doc.Descendants("metric").Attributes();
```

My output from LINQpad looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> (11 items) 
name="siteTotal" 
dataType="numeric" 
name="waterUseTotal" 
dataType="numeric" 
name="totalGHGEmissions" 
uom="MtCO2e" 
dataType="numeric" 
name="greenPowerOnSite" 
dataType="numeric"
```

As you can see it is not capturing all the attributes, most notably it only has one uom attribute. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used LINQPad and am getting the correct result using:

```
propMetrics.Descendants("metric").Attributes()
```

The only thing that I think could be happening here is some encoding problems in the string returned from the third party API. Try copying the xml from you question to LINQPad and testing to confirm this.

Comment: You can use [`Encoding.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx) to change the encoding. But even for that you need to know which encoding the string was in the first place. Play around with some encodings to find out which encoding the string uses and convert it to UTF8 or UTF16. I think that should solve the problem.

Comment: The response headers say the encoding is UTF8, does this mean I need to convert to UTF16?

Comment: Hmmm...not really. I'm pretty sure .Net is able to handle UTF-8 just fine. This requires more inspection. You need to check and find the offending characters. I suggest you create a new question for that one. There should be some tools to help with that.

Comment: The code actually runs fine in Visual Studio, it's only LINQpad that has an issue so maybe the bug lies there.